# C++ Depth First Search (DFS) showing wrong result

Tags: c++, graph

I'm trying to implement Depth First Search (DFS) in C++ but it doesn't show the correct output. Nodes that are already visited should not appear again yet they do and more than once, I really don't get why this is happening.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int id;
    vector<Node> adj;
    bool visited;
};

struct Graph{
    vector<Node> nodes;
};

void addEdge(Graph& g,int ida,int idb){
    g.nodes[ida].adj.push_back(g.nodes[idb]);
    g.nodes[idb].adj.push_back(g.nodes[ida]);
}

void dfs(Graph& g,Node& n){
    n.visited = true;
    cout << n.id << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < n.adj.size();i++)
        if (!n.adj[i].visited)
            dfs(g,n.adj[i]);
}

void init(Graph& g,int n){
    g.nodes.clear();
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        Node v;
        v.id = i;
        v.visited = false;
        g.nodes.push_back(v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Graph g;
    init(g,5);
    addEdge(g,1,3);
    addEdge(g,0,4);
    addEdge(g,1,4);
    addEdge(g,2,1);
    for (int i = 0;i < g.nodes.size();i++)
        dfs(g,g.nodes[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

#### What I think should be the output

```
0 4 1 3 2
```

#### The actual output

```
0 4 1 3 4 0 4 2 1 3 4 0 4 2 1 3 4 0 4 3 1 3 4 0 4 1 3 4 0 4
```

Comment: @sagi I only get 0 4 nothing more

Comment: There is something wrong with your implementation. Using this signature for DFS `void dfs(Graph& g,int nodeId)`gave me better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing your adjacency list with `Node` instead of pointers to nodes.

```
vector<Node*> adj;

g.nodes[ida].adj.push_back(&(g.nodes[idb]));
g.nodes[idb].adj.push_back(&(g.nodes[ida]));
```

Of course, this only works if you do the adjacency after pushing all nodes on the graph.

When you check the flag on the adjacency list `!n.adj[i].visited`, this is done on the copy of the node, not the one that you already visited.

Also, you should initialized `visited` properly.

Comment: that works but I still don't understand why, could you clarify a bit?

Comment: The adjacency vector cannot store object themselves, they would be local copies of your graph nodes. It's not like in Java or Python where you get references. In C++ you are using the object themselves, except when using explicitly pointers or references.

Answer (score -1):

You only need to call the dfs once to get the desired output, length wise. Your calling it 5x that is why the output is so long.

Comment: @Stucketmarine even if I call it with 0 it would give 0 4 which is wrong

Comment: That would not make a difference if the flag was set properly, but it's not because it's set on a copy of the node (well, it would still display the fact that you are trying to do a call as the first call always displays something).

Comment: Was merely pointing out an additional logical error, not providing a full solution... With the loop, it would still print the extra values called and not the proper expected solution even if the rest of the logic was fixed. Dissapointed in the downvote.